# Want to extract tags from XElements and display as grid on ASP.NET Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, webforms

I am writing a cloud service and using ASP.NET web role with WebForm.

In my code I get data in `XElement` and now I want to extract data from it and display it in table or grid format on WebForm

My `XElement` contains few `<entry>` tags like the following:

```
<entry xml:base="https://STORAGE_ACCOUNT.table.core.windows.net/"           xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"     xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"         m:etag="W/"datetime'2013-09-08T07%3A19%3A07.2189243Z'""    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>https://STORAGE_ACCOUNT.table.core.windows.net/authors(PartitionKey='Beckett',RowKey='Molloy')</id>
  <title type="text"></title>
  <updated>2013-09-08T07:19:07Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="authors" href="authors(PartitionKey='Beckett',RowKey='Molloy')" />
  <category term="STORAGE_ACCOUNT.authors" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:PartitionKey>Beckett</d:PartitionKey>
      <d:RowKey>Molloy</d:RowKey>
      <d:Timestamp m:type="Edm.DateTime">2013-09-08T07:19:07.2189243Z</d:Timestamp>
      <d:Artist>Beckett</d:Artist>
      <d:Title>Molloy</d:Title>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

and I want to extract the following tags

```
<d:Artist>Beckett</d:Artist>
<d:Title>Molloy</d:Title>
```

and display data in tabular format on ASPX webform like below

```
Artist   Title
Beckett  Moelly
```

How can I do this in my code?

I saw some examples of binding to Dataset but it works with xml file on some drive but for I have it in my code. I also saw people suggesting using XSLT to convert XML to HTML and then display it but I do not know how to do that in code. Please provide me pointers

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you did want to do this using LINQ to XML rather than one of your other options, it's pretty simple:

```
XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
XNamespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"

foreach (var entry in element.Descendants(atom + "entry"))
{
    var artist = (string)entry.Descendants(d + "Artist").Single();
    var title = (string)entry.Descendants(d + "Title").Single();

    // ... do something with these values
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried  what you said. However, my xelement contains sequence of <entry> tags like above.

Comment: @Fairy I updated to show how you would iterate through each entry and get the artist and title values.

Comment: thank you. I did it the same way for sequence. Now I am trying to figure out how to display Artist and Title data as table on MVC View. I am new to ASP.NEt and MVC and figuring out how this can be passed on to model. My model looks like public class DataModel
    {
        public string Artist { get; set; }

        public string Author { get; set; }
        
    } and from my controller is like this public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Xelement entity = TableHelper.GetEntities("table1");
            return View();
        }. View is created with List Template using the DataModel